# window.print then redirect from codebehind c#

Tags: c#, javascript, redirect, printing, code-behind

I have searched every possible way and I'm stuck :( hopefully somebody can give me some pointers on how to accomplish the following:

Page1 opens page2

page2 as windows.print() after it prints i would like for it to redirect back to page1

now page2 loads information in codebehind on page_load after its done loading the it prints if I put a response.redirect after its done loading the page then it never prints. Hope its understandable so that someone can give me some sort of solution.

I've tried to put a timer but the problem is that the user might not print right away or they have to wait for the computer to recognize the printer or any other situation so I have to rely on it printing and then redirecting.

Also the redirect must pass a variable from codebehind so what I'm thinking is maybe calling the windows.print from codebehind and passing that parameter so after its done it can redirect from javascript with the correct value?  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may get better responses by pasting the code you do have, so those trying to answer have some frame of reference

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is just to open `page2` in a new window with `window.open();` Then the user prints, and closes the window. Simple, clean, effective.

Comment: this kind of system doesn't allow me to open a new window.  Is there a way to generate a page from code behind and print it? cause that would be the only other way I can do it if this isn't possible.

Comment: Are you generating the page client-side or server-side?